# Install Sharepoint Designer 2007?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am new to Sharepoint.

I setup a Sharepoint Server using VM Ware.

The server is Windows Server 2003 with VS2008, SQL2005 and Sharepoint 2007. All up and running fine.

Now I want to install Sharepoint Designer 2007 on this Server.

So I basically want to know if this is the correct sequence and if I can go ahead and proceed with the installation.

Kind Regards

Sujit P

Comment: SharePoint Designer can be installed anytime. You can proceed with the installation. It can be downloaded from below url: http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=21581

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Now your SharePoint server is up and running. You can now install Sharepoint designer.

You can download it from http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=21581

For installation instructions :

http://grok.lsu.edu/Article.aspx?articleId=6325

Comment: in the article above they have mentioned that it will ask for Product Key, i guess SPD is free and it won't require any product key.

Comment: No, you can install without any key.